# How to break a Tie for a 3-of-a-kind

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

In a particular scenario where there is a tie for same three of a kind.

Two players -

User1 with 10h and 6d

User2 with 10d and 4c

On table 10c, 10s, Kc, 3h, 2d

Who wins?

Note: h/d/s/c = Hearts/Diamonds/Spades/Clubs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When figuring out who wins in Texas Holdem you take the best 5 card hand a player can make using their 2 cards plus the 5 community cards on the table. That gives us:

Player 1: 10, 10, 10, K, 6
Player 2: 10, 10, 10, K, 4

Since they both match on the 3 tens you look to the highest kicker card, in this case they both have kings so you need to look at the next highest card. For this card Player 1 has a 6 and Player 2 has a 4 so Player 1 will win the hand.

Reference: [Texas Holdem Rules](http://www.pokerlistings.com/poker-rules-texas-holdem)

Comment: And if they have the same best 5 cards, they split the pot.

Comment: Is suit taken into account for the three of a kind cards?